# Python Django 1.11 "ValueError Incomplete format" in admin action when trying to update FK field

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I have a simple master/detail model of **Quotation** (Master) containing the header info and totals, and **QuotationDetail** (Detail) containing the Quotation Items, this child model has a **PriceLevel FK field** used to calculate the markup for each individual item.  I am trying to implement a Django Admin Action so the admin can change this PriceLevel on several Items at once, but I get the error:

```
[myProjectPath]\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 812, in get_action_choices
    choice = (name, description % model_format_dict(self.opts))
ValueError: incomplete format
```

This is my **models.py** (on the relevant models):

```
class NivelDePrecio(models.Model):    # PriceLevel
    # Fields
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = extension_fields.AutoSlugField(populate_from='nombre', blank=True)
    valor = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=4)
    factor = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=6, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-valor',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.factor = 1 / (1 - self.valor)
        super(NivelDePrecio, self).save()


class Cotizacion(models.Model):   # Quotation (master)
    # Fields
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = extension_fields.AutoSlugField(populate_from='nombre', blank=True, overwrite=True)
    fecha_ida = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    fecha_regreso = models.DateField(default=date.today)

    # Relationship Fields
    itinerario = models.ForeignKey(Itinerario, on_delete=CASCADE, verbose_name='itinerario')
    nivel_de_precio = models.ForeignKey(NivelDePrecio, verbose_name='nivel de precio',
                                        on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('itinerario__cliente__codigo', '-fecha_ida')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.nombre)


class CotizacionDetalle(models.Model):  # QuotationDetail (detail)
    # Fields
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    cantidad = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    costo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0, editable=False)
    monto = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0, editable=False)
    markup = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=4, default=0, editable=False)
    utilidad = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=4, default=0, editable=False)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0, editable=False)
    slug = extension_fields.AutoSlugField(populate_from='item', blank=True)

    # Relationship Fields
    cotizacion = models.ForeignKey(Cotizacion, on_delete=CASCADE, verbose_name='cotizacion', related_name='lineas')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, verbose_name='item', related_name='item')
    nivel_de_precio = models.ForeignKey(NivelDePrecio, verbose_name='nivel de precio',
                                        on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.descripcion = self.item.descripcion_venta
        self.costo = self.item.costo
        self.monto = self.cantidad * self.costo
        if self.nivel_de_precio is None:
            self.nivel_de_precio = self.cotizacion.nivel_de_precio
        self.markup = Decimal(round(self.nivel_de_precio.factor - 1, 4)).quantize(Decimal("0.0000"))
        self.utilidad = Decimal(self.nivel_de_precio.valor).quantize(Decimal("0.0000"))
        self.total = Decimal(self.monto) * (1 + Decimal(self.markup))
        super(CotizacionDetalle, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.descripcion)
```

This is my **admin.py**:  (I have also tried the commented version of the action with the same resulting error).  It would be nice to be able to select options for this change from the FK model, but I will settle for making it work by having two actions: one to increase markup value by .05% and another to decrease markup by .05% in which cases I would need to update the markup field instead.

```
class CotizacionDetalleAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CotizacionDetalle
        fields = ['item', 'cotizacion', 'cantidad', 'nivel_de_precio']


def cambiar_utilidad(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    from .models import NivelDePrecio
    ndp = NivelDePrecio.objects.get(id=5)
    queryset.update(nivel_de_precio_id=ndp.id)
    # for cd in queryset:
    #     cd.nivel_de_precio_id = ndp.id
    #     cd.save()


cambiar_utilidad.short_description = "Cambiar Utilidad 25%"


class CotizacionDetalleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # save_as = True
    form = CotizacionDetalleAdminForm
    list_display = ['cliente', 'itinerario', 'cotizacion', 'descripcion',
                    'cantidad', 'costo', 'monto', 'utilidad', 'markup', 'total']
    list_display_links = ['descripcion']
    readonly_fields = ['descripcion', 'costo', 'monto', 'utilidad', 'markup', 'total', 'slug', 'creado', 'actualizado']
    search_fields = ['descripcion']
    list_filter = (('cotizacion__itinerario__cliente', DropdownFilterRelated),
                   ('cotizacion__itinerario', DropdownFilterRelated),
                   ('cotizacion', DropdownFilterRelated),)
    ordering = ['cotizacion__itinerario__cliente__codigo', 'cotizacion__fecha_ida', 'id']
    actions = [cambiar_utilidad]


admin.site.register(CotizacionDetalle, CotizacionDetalleAdmin)
```

Update:

...tried this:

https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1836/

as follows in my **admin.py**

```
def create_action_nivel(nivel):
    def action(modeladmin, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(nivel_de_precio=nivel)

    name = "change_to_%s" % (nivel.slug,)
    return (name, (action, name, "Cambiar Nivel de Precio a: %s" % (nivel,)))
```

...

```
class CotizacionDetalleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_actions(self, request):
        return dict(create_action_nivel(n) for n in NivelDePrecio.objects.all())
```

But I get the same error, traceback shown here: http://dpaste.com/360GEJY

The same snippet works just fine when the field to update is not a **Foreign Key Field**. I used it in a different **Model** and works just fine:

```
def create_action_estatus(estatus):
    def action(modeladmin, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(estatus=estatus)

    name = "mark_%s" % (estatus,)
    return name, (action, name, "Cambiar Estatus: %s " % (estatus,))


class ItinerarioAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_actions(self, request):
        statuses= [ "Solicitado", "Cotizado", "Confirmado", "Facturado", "Cerrado"]
        return dict(create_action_estatus(e) for e in statuses)
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the error, after many trials, the problem is in the usage of the **%** symbol inside the content of a description field, apparently when creating 
 admin actions dynamically the **short_description** generated string is reused and if it has a % sign inside it throws the Incomplete format error.

The solution was to build the **short_description** string like this:

```
cambiar_nivel.short_description = "Cambiar Nivel de Precio a {0:.1f}%%".format(nivel.valor * 100)
```

...note the (escaped) double % sign